# Which animation approach for two circles which are circling?

Tags: java, android, animation, view

I want to display two circles, with different colors (might change them dynamically) and let both circle. There is a different range of ways to get animation going. Animating objects, using canvas, etc. and I am still confused which one would be the right approach.

I was thinking of extending `View` and overwriting `onDraw(Canvas)` is that right?

Comment: You can use SurfaceView. It will render the ui easily and efficiently.

Comment: you can definitely go that way, imo

Comment: I am just wondering if it wouldn't be better to have some way of defining the animation in a XML file, but I think that's not how it's done using `Surface(View)`

Answer (score 1):

Really you should look at using some existing frameworks rather than re-inventing the wheel. Depending on just what you are doing look for android animation and/or graphics/games libraries and find one with the facilities you need.

Comment: While I really appreciate your post, it's rather a comment than an answer, unless you point me towards the appropriate library to use.

Comment: There are a multitude of libraries and honestly I'm not sure which are better than others (especially as I have no knowledge of your overall requirements. (Unfortunately asking for library recommendations which is off topic for StackOverflow). Try google and then evaluate the first few results. Libgdx for example has a good reputation.

Comment: Yeah, basically that's the problem. Libgdx looks like a library you would use to do heavy graphic animations, for instance when implementing a game. I just want to let two 2D circles move around and maybe fade.